# Online resource for solved ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm looking for some sort of list of solved ODEs, that is, ODEs with solution included. I was hoping to find something like this on the internet but I haven't been able to. Does someone know of a place?

I'm basically looking for standard "solvable-by-quadrature" ODEs, simply to gain some mechanical ability and "pattern recognition", if you will. I know plenty of books but my school's library is closed these days.

Comment: Why not just let wolfram alpha solve it (if you don't have Mathematica)? Then you don't have to scroll through a website to find the one similar problem. Also, the more you solve the easier patterns will be to recognize. For instance, a simple harmonic oscillator is pretty easy to recognize as well as damped once you have solved them.

Comment: @dustin You have a very good point about wolfram, I use it all the time to check solutions, but it won't always help me in cases where I don't know where to start. The same goes for your second remark, I sort of need a jump start so I can actually get to solving a bunch of equations, so that this in turn will help me solve $more$ equations. I've been putting off the whole "solving" part until now and just studying existence theorems, asymptotics, stability and all the fun stuff.

Comment: @dustin ... So as a result of my theoretical meanderings I find even the humblest of first order equations may stump me.

Comment: I think an easy to use and understand book to pick up would be Dennis Zill's ODE book. It goes over many examples and an older copy shouldn't be too expensive. That is, you will have problems to work through an tutorials in the beginning of the sections. I believe this will be a lot more useful then small snippets from a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find not only ordinary, but also partial and integral equations:

http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/

Comment: The page doesn't seem to load. Perhaps it's a regional thing (I'm in Spain). Thank you anyways.

Comment: @GPerez I cannot open it either, but it did work yesterday for me (US). Give a try a couple days later.

Comment: Ok I will keep trying.

Comment: @GPerez It works now :) Check it out.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Unfortunately the ship has sailed; my test was yesterday. I'll need it in the future though!

Answer (score 1):

i have found this here i hope this will help you

http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf?